# How to get the list of published artifacts from an Azure DevOps build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

Azure DevOps provides a view of published artifacts after a build has completed, my question is, is there an API endpoint that lists these artifacts?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This API is not officially documented, but you can get it from the developers tools in the Artifacts page.

So, the API url is:

`https://dev.azure.com/{org-id}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery/project/{project-id}`

And the body should be:

```
{
    "contributionIds":  [
                            "ms.vss-build-web.run-artifacts-data-provider"
                        ],
    "dataProviderContext":  {
                                "properties":  {
                                                   "artifactId":  {artifact-id},
                                                   "buildId":  {build-id},
                                                   "sourcePage":  {
                                                                      "url":  "https://dev.azure.com/{org-id}/{project-id}/_build/results?buildId=1210\u0026view=artifacts\u0026pathAsName=false\u0026type=publishedArtifacts",
                                                                      "routeId":  "ms.vss-build-web.ci-results-hub-route",
                                                                      "routeValues":  {
                                                                                          "project":  "{project-id}",
                                                                                          "viewname":  "build-results",
                                                                                          "controller":  "ContributedPage",
                                                                                          "action":  "Execute",
                                                                                          "serviceHost":  "{host-id} ({username})"
                                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                               }
                            }
}
```

In the response you will get `items` section with the file names.

You can in the first to go the build artifacts page, press on <kbd>F12</kbd> and see the values for the `{}` in the body I provided.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that endpoint and it give me an object describing the drop container, but doesn't list the file names. Is there an endpoint that lists just the file names, or do I need to query the container?

Answer (score 0):

There is an API available to get a list of artifacts for a pipeline build

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/artifacts?api-version=7.1-preview.5
```

It returns a list of all artifacts for the pipeline build.
Official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1